# Simplifying H-bridge circuit

Tags: h-bridge, shoot-through

I am currently trying to build a PWM H-bridge. It has a power line of 12 V and the Arduino Uno provides the PWM. The MOSFETs I have are: IRLZ44S (N-channel) and FQD11P06TM (P-channel). Basically, the P-type MOSFETs go in the upper side of the circuit and the N-channel ones go at the bottom.

I would be building 6 of these circuits to run 6 motors in an ROV. At the moment I am using this circuit (see image below), but I have been told that it might have problems due to problems of shoot-through currents which could burn the MOSFETS so I would have to add some capacitors. I honestly don't know which resistor values I should use and where to place the capacitors (or their values). Any help will be appreciated.

I am more than welcome to accept a different H-bridge circuit which is simpler than the other one as it uses BJTs and, ideally, I would only like to use a simple circuit with only 4 transistors (the MOSFETs).

[image: H-bridge circuit:]

Comment: You can't get around shoot through without independent control of transistors. I don't see how capacitors would help.

Comment: @Toor Why not? If the P FET turns off much slower than the N FET turns on, you have shoot though.

Comment: @Toor Brain fart! AROUND. You wrote around... I read any. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh okay. I was scratching my head when reading your comment thinking "but the PMOS in that circuit would turn off slower than the NMOS turns on?"

Comment: It is possible to implement a fast turn-off and slow turn-on using resistors, capacitors, and diodes. But that doesn't address the OP's desire to use a minimum number of components.

Comment: (`[passive dead-time doesn't] use a minimum number of components` just tinkered with that (simulation only) and second that notion.)

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofD0z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This h-bridge cannot have shoot through because the upper transistors are switched off before the lower ones are turned on and vice-a-versa.
There will not be quite +12V across the motor because of the transistor Vbe drops so it will run a little slower.
Don't forget to add the back emf snubbing diodes.